# webpack.DefinePlugin | constant will change only if file changes

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

How can I resolve this issue?

*Steps:*

1. [START AT **12:00**]: webpack --watch
2. webpack will create process.env.DATE = "05.07.2017 **12:00**"
3. [AT **12:01**]: I'm changing random file
4. webpack will change process.env.DATE = "05.07.2017 **12:01**"
5. **5** minutes of silence
6. [AT **12:06**]: I'm changing random file
7. webpack will change process.env.DATE = "05.07.2017 **12:06**"
8. ...loop

*webpack.config.js*

```
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      'DATE': // new Date()...
    }
  })
]
...
```

*index.js*

```
...
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>Last updated at [{process.env.DATE}]</div>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
...
```